# Strange mistake in this proof about normed separable vector spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am supposed to prove that an infinite-dimensionale separable normed space $X$ constains a countable subset $Y$ that is linearly independent and dense.

There are three hints given: 
First, prove that no subspace of X contains an open ball.
Second, prove that $\overline{\{x_n;n \in \mathbb{N}\}} = X$ and $||x_n-y_n|| \le \frac{1}{n}$ for all n and therefore $\overline{\{y_n;n \in \mathbb{N} \} }=X$.

Finally, construct the set inductively.

My proof of the first hint: Assuming false, then some $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset X' \subsetneq X$, where X' and X are both vector spaces. But in that case there is some vector $w \in X \backslash X'$ and therefore we have that $x + \frac{\epsilon}{2 |w|}w \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, but since $x \in X'$ it would follow that since $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset X'$ we have $w \in X'$ which is wrong.

My second proof is: Assuming false, then $\exists x \in X \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: d(x,y_n) \ge \frac{1}{m} $

Since the $x_n$ are dense we can say that there are at least infinitely many $x_n$ such that $d(x_n,x)\le \frac{1}{2m}$.
So we get that: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: d(x,x_n)+ d(x_n,y_n) \ge d(x,y_n) \ge \frac{1}{m}$, but this can't be true, since we know that for infinitely many $d(x,x_n)$ is small and for $n > m+1$ we have that $d(x_n,y_n) \leq \frac{1}{m+1}$. So contradiction.

Now I wanted to construct the countable dense and linear independent set in the following way:
Step 1 :  $ y_1:=x_1$ and therefore $Y=\{x_1\}$. This is of course linearly independent and we have $|x_1-y_1|=0$.

Step n to n+1: $Y=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ be constructed.
Now if $x_{n+1} \in span(Y)$ then we choose some vector in $X$ that is not in $span(Y)$ and say $y_{n+1} = x_{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}\frac{w}{||w||}$. This is leaves Y linearly independet and $|y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$
If $x_{n+1} \not \in  span(Y)$, we set $y_{n+1} = x_{n+1}$. In that case Y is also linearly independent and $|y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}|=0\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$.

In that case we get a set $Y$ that is linearly independent and countable and by the second hint that I proved it is also dense in $X$. *But the problem is: I did not use hint 1, so my proof is probably wrong! So, where is my mistake?*

Comment: First of all, simply because you didn't use a hint, it doesn't mean that your proof is wrong. Second, your ideas are good, just try to write them a little better. Now, think about this: (a) what if $x_1=0$? (b) why can you choose a vector $w$ which is not in $\text{span} Y$?

Comment: okay, so we can deal with (a) if we choose any vector that is not $x=0$. I can choose a $w$ that is not in this span, cause Y is the span of a finite set of vectors, but the vector space is infinite-dimensional(hence there are infinitely many vectors that are linearly independent and there is a theorem in linear algebra that says that you can add linearly independent vectors to a span that stays linearly independent, as long as you have not reached the maximum number of basis elements.

Comment: You should only worry that $\Vert y_1-x_1\Vert\leq 1$. Now, the set $Y$ that you obtained seems linearly independent and dense to me, so I don't really see any problem with your proof... Maybe the first hint would be for you to do the following: Since $\text{span}\left\{y_1,\ldots,y_n,x_{n+1}\right\}$ does not contain any open ball, then, in particular, it does not contain $B_{1/(n+1)}(x_{n+1})$, so you get your $y_{n+1}\in B_{1/(n+1)}(x_{n+1})\setminus \text{span}\left\{y_1,\ldots,y_n,x_{n+1}\right\}$

Comment: yes, thank you. do you have any idea, what our professor could have had in mind, when he gave us the first hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the first hint is: if $x_n$ happens to be in the span of some previously chosen vectors, a small perturbation will get it out of there. This is possible precisely because a proper subspace has no interior points. An interior point wouldn't be able to get out of the set with an arbitrarily small perturbation.

The reason you did not use the first hint is that you incorporated it as a part of your proof, where you let $y_{n+1} = x_{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}\frac{w}{\|w\|}$ and argue that $y_{n+1}$ is not in the span. The version using the hint would not involve $w$; it would simply say: pick $y_{n+1}$ such that $\|y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}\|<\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ is not in the span of $y_1,\dots,y_n$.